# Is it possible to run Chrome with and without web security at the same time?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I [recently found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16012197/388916) that I can disable Chrome "web security" using a command line argument, making JavaScript development easier. The issue is that I can't seem to run more than one "instance" of Chrome at a time. If I `chrome.exe --disable-web-security` while Chrome is alread running, it just opens a new window within the running instance and ignores my command line arguments. I can close Chrome completely and relaunch it with the above command line argument, but then all my windows will be running without web security, which is a bad thing for general browser usage.

So to summarize the question: Is it possible to start an instance of Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag while a normal Chrome instance is running?

---

*Note:* I suspect the answer may lay within the [Chrome command line switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), but there are just... so many...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found a [similar question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/35392/52719). Apparently you can tell Chrome to start a new session by passing it a new user data directory. This means I can now run this command:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

And a new Chrome window opens with web security disabled. Yay!

---

*Note:* This means that window drag & drop won't work between these two windows.

Comment: `You can tell Chrome to start a new session by passing it a new user data directory.`   Yup; in fact, it does this with most switches; an “instance” is Chrome run with a unique set of arguments (in any order). It may not behave exactly the same now, but `user-data-dir` at a minimum will still trigger a new instance.     `Window drag & drop won't work between these two windows.`   Nope; as far as Chrome is concerned, they are from two different browsers/apps. Also be wary of handlers: running an `.htm` file or bookmark will open in an instance with the args specified in the type registration.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in Mac OS X?

Comment: @aug: I can't test this, but try (from the terminal): `open -a /Applications/Chrome.app --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security`. I'm assuming here that OSX has a "/tmp/" directory, you can change the path if it doesn't.

Comment: Hmmm didn't work. I played around with the file path too @_@ tried things like `$TMPDIR` and such. Might play with it more later when I get the chance.

Comment: @aug: Tell me if you figure it out, I'll add it to the answer :)

Comment: I'm getting this `you are using an unsupported command-line flag disable-web-security`

Comment: For osx you can do: `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session_das_work_order" --disable-web-security`

Comment: @CoryMawhorter This is already in an answer below

Answer (score 6):

Close all the opened windows in the Chrome browser. If multiple windows are opened, close everything separately. Then you can open Chrome using the following code in **"RUN"**:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

Answer (score 4):

For Mac:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security
```

Replace with your particular path to Chrome if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Responding to @aug and @hubro's comments, you can use the `open` command's `-n` flag to open a new instance of an app via Mac OS X's Terminal:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Chrome.app
```

You can add any flags that you want to use (like `--disable-web-security`) onto the end of that command.

Comment: This doesnt seem to create a new instance. Because when I try it in the old instance (with security not disabled) I can do cors

Comment: Huh, you're right! The man page of the `open` command does indicate that the `-n` flag is for opening a new instance of an application, but it seems like Chrome & Chromium have some kind of logic preventing multiple instances of the application from being opened. The command works as is for Safari, for example.

Comment: Since this answer is incorrect, can you delete it?

Comment: I don't have a mac, but I heard that it works if you include the --user-data-dir option also:  `open -n -a /Applications/Chrome.app --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session" --disable-web-security`.  Please give that a try.

Comment: @SamWatkins's approach worked for me in macOS Sierra, but only after adding the `--args` flag and opening the Chrome executable (not the Chrome.app container); so: `open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_session_2" --disable-web-security`

Answer (score 1):

You can use some fork of Chrome as a second browser, like [Iron](http://www.srware.net/en/software_srware_iron.php) or [Dragon](http://www.comodo.com/home/browsers-toolbars/browser.php). Maybe a [portable instance](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) of Chrome would work too.